# If $(a-2)<0$ then what is the value range of a for $-2 < -a/(a-2) <1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

On solving

$$-2 < \frac{-a}{a-2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad\frac{-a}{a-2}<1$$ I get 
$$
2a-4> a \qquad \text{and} \qquad-2a<-2
$$
 which implies that $a>4$ and $a>1$. However this is part of a bigger question whose final result is that $a$'s value range is from negative infinity to $-\frac14$ and this does not correspond to that. What is wrong in my approach and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $a-2<0$ then how can $a>4$ or $a>1$?

Comment: I'm guessing that when you multiplied through by $a-2$ in the first step you assumed $a-2>0$. What if $a-2<0$?

Comment: @JeremyUpsal ohhh ok thanks! On doing that I got a<4 and a<1 which corresponds to the answer.

Comment: You just have to be careful in when the inequality sign flips (that is, when you're multiplying by a negative quantity).
$$
\frac{-a}{a-2}<1 \qquad \Rightarrow \quad -a > a-2  \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad a<1
$$